# ¿Es posible hacer un random con un array dependiente del select?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un input dependiente de un select, que al elegir una ciudad del select, él elige un usuario del array, pero en Bogotá tengo 2 usuarios, y he estado leyendo sobre la función Math.random(), y me gustaría aplicarlo sobre esta parte del arrary para que al elegir en el select la cuidad de Bogotá, aleatoriamente me elija un usuario de los 2 que tengo. ¿Es posible con esta función o con otra función puedo lograrlo, o no es posible hacer una selección aleatoria en el array?

Este es mi input:

```
<input name="assigned_user_id" id="assigned_user_id" value="" type="hidden" />
```

Mi Script:

```
var primary_address_city ={
        //contenerdores de usuarios por cuidad
        "" : [""],
        "Barranquilla": ["6010c553-af30-0e0b-2ea6-5d951ca3f8ff","red_nacional"],//iosorio(RD)
        "Bogota": ["9a64c594-f9a6-d5f4-4ba0-5da5fd12923f","e1dbaa7e-e480-a25a-2692-5dbc5876368e","retail"],//lclavijo(LM)
        "Bucaramanga": ["9eb0ec0f-4f02-b03a-636e-5d95241fa66b","red_nacional"],//msalamanca(RD)
        "Cali": ["af044b68-1633-d103-34ba-5d951da46ef6","red_nacional"],//apaez(RD)
        "Cucuta": ["473c8920-29dd-c615-13ad-5d95224e0ac9","red_nacional"],//hmoreno(RD)
        "Duitama": ["7372f886-0cd8-f116-9363-5d9525bc3cda","red_nacional"],//nbecera(RD)
        "Ipiales":["7d31cf28-489b-f68b-20d9-5d9520ce7149","red_nacional"],//aluna(RD)
        "Manizales": ["c5d4cad7-6b6d-3581-561f-5d9524ce8fdc","red_nacional"],//nathaliar(RD)
        "Medellin": ["196d9776-b327-b310-7995-5d95191b0c3f","retail"],//dlopez(R)
        "Monteria": ["9cce90b6-ea25-54a2-b089-5d952118591c","red_nacional"],//dsandoval(RD)
        "Neiva": ["6168281c-e101-9289-ebf6-5d95189b4459","retail"],//tjaramillo(R)
        "Palmira": ["af9f0654-8d46-3636-6fed-5d952349462b","red_nacional"],//jreyes(RD)
        "Pasto": ["19ff3b33-562d-5a04-e5d2-5d952167f28f","red_nacional"],//ccolorado(RD)
        "Pereira": ["c5d4cad7-6b6d-3581-561f-5d9524ce8fdc","red_nacional"],//nathaliar(RD)
        "Tulua": ["c5d4cad7-6b6d-3581-561f-5d9524ce8fdc","red_nacional"],//nathaliar(RD)
        "Valledupar": ["a097f5c5-d52e-e30b-d96d-5dcd5dde1184","red_nacional"],//mramirez(RD)
        "Villavicencio": ["c907049d-8ac7-89d4-fb69-5d9519d738e2","red_nacional"],//smartinez(RD)
        "Yopal": ["9f7d3831-042b-67e7-7e12-5d9523f679f6","red_nacional"]//jcastaneda(RD)
    }

    function cambioCiudades() {
        /*
        -   Función de asignación de usurario por ciudad, en suitecrm, al envió del formulario

        -   la variable contenedor es la cual llama a las usuarios por ciudad
        -   la variable ciudad es quien revisa el valor del contenedor 
        */

        var contenedor = document.getElementById('primary_address_city');
        var ciudad = contenedor.value;


        document.getElementById('assigned_user_id').value = primary_address_city[ciudad][0]; //envía el usuario dependiendo de la cuidad
}
```

Comment: Yo solo veo una entrada para Bogota.

Comment: Disculpa lo olvide agregar, ya lo agregue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que necesitas:

```
var myArray = [
  "Apples",
  "Bananas",
  "Pears"
];

var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

document.body.innerHTML = randomItem;
```

Comment: Una explicación uno solo codigo Le daría más calidad a la respuesta y la haría más entendible

Answer (score 0):

```js
(() => {
  const MAX_ARRAY_TWO_USER = 3;
  const SELECT_TWO_USER = 2;
  const SELECT_DEFAULT_USER = 0;
  const primary_address_city = {
    "": [""],
    "Barranquilla": ["6010c553-af30-0e0b-2ea6-5d951ca3f8ff", "red_nacional"], //iosorio(RD)
    "Bogota": ["9a64c594-f9a6-d5f4-4ba0-5da5fd12923f", "e1dbaa7e-e480-a25a-2692-5dbc5876368e", "retail"], //lclavijo(LM)
    "Bucaramanga": ["9eb0ec0f-4f02-b03a-636e-5d95241fa66b", "red_nacional"], //msalamanca(RD)
    "Cali": ["af044b68-1633-d103-34ba-5d951da46ef6", "red_nacional"], //apaez(RD)
    "Cucuta": ["473c8920-29dd-c615-13ad-5d95224e0ac9", "red_nacional"], //hmoreno(RD)
    "Duitama": ["7372f886-0cd8-f116-9363-5d9525bc3cda", "red_nacional"], //nbecera(RD)
    "Ipiales": ["7d31cf28-489b-f68b-20d9-5d9520ce7149", "red_nacional"], //aluna(RD)
    "Manizales": ["c5d4cad7-6b6d-3581-561f-5d9524ce8fdc", "red_nacional"], //nathaliar(RD)
    "Medellin": ["196d9776-b327-b310-7995-5d95191b0c3f", "retail"], //dlopez(R)
    "Monteria": ["9cce90b6-ea25-54a2-b089-5d952118591c", "red_nacional"], //dsandoval(RD)
    "Neiva": ["6168281c-e101-9289-ebf6-5d95189b4459", "retail"], //tjaramillo(R)
    "Palmira": ["af9f0654-8d46-3636-6fed-5d952349462b", "red_nacional"], //jreyes(RD)
    "Pasto": ["19ff3b33-562d-5a04-e5d2-5d952167f28f", "red_nacional"], //ccolorado(RD)
    "Pereira": ["c5d4cad7-6b6d-3581-561f-5d9524ce8fdc", "red_nacional"], //nathaliar(RD)
    "Tulua": ["c5d4cad7-6b6d-3581-561f-5d9524ce8fdc", "red_nacional"], //nathaliar(RD)
    "Valledupar": ["a097f5c5-d52e-e30b-d96d-5dcd5dde1184", "red_nacional"], //mramirez(RD)
    "Villavicencio": ["c907049d-8ac7-89d4-fb69-5d9519d738e2", "red_nacional"], //smartinez(RD)
    "Yopal": ["9f7d3831-042b-67e7-7e12-5d9523f679f6", "red_nacional"] //jcastaneda(RD)
  }

  function ChangeCity(e) {
    try {
      const valueSelectCity = e.target.value;
      if (Array.isArray(primary_address_city[valueSelectCity])) {
        maxArray = primary_address_city[valueSelectCity].length;
        if (maxArray === MAX_ARRAY_TWO_USER) {
          document.getElementById("assigned_user_id").value = primary_address_city[valueSelectCity][GetRandomInt(SELECT_TWO_USER)];
        } else document.getElementById("assigned_user_id").value = primary_address_city[valueSelectCity][SELECT_DEFAULT_USER];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("ChangeCity =>", e);
    }
  }

  function GetRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  }
  document.getElementById("selectCity").addEventListener("change", ChangeCity, false)

})();
```

```html
<select id="selectCity">
  <option value="Barranquilla">Barranquilla</option>
  <option value="Bogota">Bogota</option>
  <option value="Valledupar">Valledupar</option>
  <option selected value="Medellin">Medellin</option>
</select>
<input name="assigned_user_id" id="assigned_user_id" value="a097f5c5-d52e-e30b-d96d-5dcd5dde1184" />
```

Puedes Utilizar está función para generar un numero aleatoria hasta el número máximo "NO INCLUIDO".

Comment: ¿O sea puedo hacer que se muestre en un input?

Comment: Si, te deje un ejemplo.